# XTS object not recognized by plot.xts

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I converted my data set to a time-series using xts but when I go to plot the data, R comes back with an error code saying 'x' must be a time series. When I check the class it shows it as an xts zoo object. I have checked the classes of my variables and noticed that they are all factors of one level. Before converting it they were the correct class.

I have tried converting the class of variables after making it an xts object but that does nothing. I have also tried the same method on different data and the other data worked as it's supposed to.

```
rm(list = ls())
tmp = read.csv('file:///C:/Users/cxbon/Documents/R_practice/train_forecast.csv')

head(tmp, 1)
tail(tmp, 1)

time.index = seq(from = as.POSIXct('2012-08-25 00:00'),
                 to = as.POSIXct('2014-09-25 23:00'), by = "hour")

tmp_ts = xts(tmp, order.by = time.index)

plot(tmp_ts)
traceback()
```

```
> dput(head(tmp, 20))
structure(list(ID = 0:19, Datetime = c("25-08-2012 00:00", "25-08-2012 01:00", 
"25-08-2012 02:00", "25-08-2012 03:00", "25-08-2012 04:00", "25-08-2012 05:00", 
"25-08-2012 06:00", "25-08-2012 07:00", "25-08-2012 08:00", "25-08-2012 09:00", 
"25-08-2012 10:00", "25-08-2012 11:00", "25-08-2012 12:00", "25-08-2012 13:00", 
"25-08-2012 14:00", "25-08-2012 15:00", "25-08-2012 16:00", "25-08-2012 17:00", 
"25-08-2012 18:00", "25-08-2012 19:00"), Count = c(8L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

once I run `plot(tmp_ts)` I get the error
`Error in plot.xts(tmp_ts) : 'x' must be a time-series object`

> ## UPDATE
>
> After continuing to look around for an answer I found a post on an R help site where someone suggested separating each column and creating an xts object from each one then `cbind` them all back together. Trying this in my code did work but now I am confused as to why xts cannot change the class without coercing all the columns to factors. Any help or knowledge of the matter would be greatly appreciated.
>
> ---

the link to the [post](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/as-xts-convert-all-my-numeric-data-to-character-td975564.html)

Comment: greetings - it might be helpful if you could provide a sample of your csv data for reproducibility such as using dput()

Comment: ok lemme do that

Comment: Alright data added. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Could you add a small dump from tmp? tmp_ts is after you combined tmp and time.index. Do note that all your data inside the xts are character values. Also tmp_ts has a date inside the xts matrix. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: would like to see `dput` of temp (sample of `train_forecast.csv`)

Comment: First of all, thank you to phiver for pointing out that I can't have a `Datetime` column in the `xts` matrix because that fixed the problem. I will upload the things you guys pointed out so it can be reproducible in the future. Thank you all for your help.